# Wordpress 3.5.1 unable to add media to pages. Media Library is blank

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Please reference the following image:

[image: Empty Media Library]

Here is what i have done:

1. Uninstalled/reinstalled from scratch WordPress 3.5.1
2. Inactivated all plugins
3. Activated the default twenty 11/12 themes one at a time
4. Cleared the cache of browsers
5. Tried to use either Chrome or Safari

All to no avail. Unfortunately everything i seem to do leads me to a media library which is blank. Please note i have several images that i have imported into my Media Library. This i have checked and double checked.

Struggling to get past this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Media Library is loaded via Ajax, check in browsers developer tools on network tab if ajax request has been successful.

Comment: @IgorJerosimić Please see my "answer" below. Thank you for your help. unfortunately it was not Ajax, but rather a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though i thought i had scoured each of my plugins, i found that this indeed was not an issue with Ajax or a browser or operating system. It was simply an issue with plugin needed for a very specific theme.

How did i find this out:

```
1) Uninstalled my current wordpress installation
2) Re-installed wordpress 3.5.1
3) Checked whether or not i could add media to a page before changing the theme 
   (using the twenty-tweleve default theme.
```

It worked!! Installed the plugin needed for my specific theme, it failed. I have chosen a different theme and all seems well.

Thanks guys!

Comment: Which plugin was the perp?